# Typescript discriminated union with default interface

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Imagine this example:

```js
interface IBase {
    type: string;
    value: number;
}

interface IA extends IBase {
    type: "A";
    a: string;
}

interface IB extends IBase {
    type: "B";
    b: string;
}

type IObj = IA | IB;

///
const val: IObj = {} as any; // don't care the inside

if (val.type === "A") {
    // val is IA (val.a exsits)
}

if (val.type === "B") {
    // val is IB (val.b exsits)
}
```

But, what happens if I want the "IBase" as "default" interface. For example:

```js
if (val.type === "XYZ") {
    // val must be "IBase"
}
```

I tried `IBase` to the `IObj` but:

```js
type IObj = IA | IB | IBase;

//
const val: IObj = {} as any; // don't care the inside

if (val.type === "A") {
    // val is "IA | IBase" (val.a not exists)
}

if (val.type === "B") {
    // val is "IB | IBase" (val.b not exists)
}

if (val.type === "XYZ") {
    // val is IBase
}
```

So, Is there a way to make a default interface using discriminated union?

Comment: you could add an `else` branch after you've checked all cases and that would be your default.

Comment: @Uzi But that only works for the "default". In the example in the first `if` the type is `IA | IBase`

Comment: remove `IBase` from `IObj` and it'll work. `IA` and `IB` already extend it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use type guards to such checks. They are used to determine does a value conform to specific interface:

```
const val: IObj = {} as any;

function isIA(arg: IObj): arg is IA {
    return arg.type === "A";
}

if (isIA(val)) {
  // here val conforms to IA interface.
}
```

Comment: This must be a solution if is impossible to handle a default value in discriminated union. In that case, I should not use the `IObj`. I must set `val` as `IBase` and the `isIA(arg: IBase): arg is IA`